# V4L2 Ошибка EIO при установки значения существующего параметра

Tags: c, virtualbox

Подскажите, может кто сталкивался с такой странной ситуацией? Не могу задать параметр `V4L2_CID_BRIGHTNESS` - `ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_CTRL, &control)` выходит с `errno == EIO`.

При этом `ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL, &queryctrl)` и `ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_G_CTRL, &control)` отрабатывают без ошибок. Флаг в `queryctrl` равен нулю - то есть параметр имеется и он не отключен (not DISABLED), описание и значение по умолчанию корректны.

Минимальный пример:

```
int fd=open("/dev/video0", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK, 0);
v4l2_queryctrl queryctrl;
queryctrl.id = V4L2_CID_BRIGHTNESS;
ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL, &queryctrl); //ok
v4l2_control control = { V4L2_CID_BRIGHTNESS, 0};
ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_G_CTRL, &control); //ok
control.value = 50;
if (-1 == ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_CTRL, &control)) {
    perror(" ");//errno == EIO
}
```

Аналогично с `v4l2-ctl`

```
$ v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 -C brightness
brightness: 50
$ v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 -c brightness=51
VIDIOC_S_CTRL: failed: Input/output error
brightness: Input/output error
```

Не исключено, что проблема в драйвере. В таком случае уточню: использую Ubuntu 16 на VirtualBox.

Comment: [mcve] очень помог бы вопросу.

Comment: выглядит всё правильно и УМВР... я бы копал в сторону отсутствия поддержки/ошибки со стороны конкретного устройства/драйвера...

Comment: Может и правда драйвер? Использую Ubuntu 16 на виртуалке. Кроме вот этой странности остальное работает и кадр приходит.

Comment: кстати, в `dmesg` ничего не падает?

Comment: uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 2 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).

Comment: нум, теперь думаю очевидно, что проблема где-то между драйвером и устройством... AFAIK uvcvideo должен быть довольно хорошо отлажен, так что я бы больше склонялся к устройству...

Comment: с устройством как раз все нормально (проверил на нескольких разных), а вот с тем как VirtualBox его пробрасывает видимо и есть проблема.И вот что-то мне подсказывает, что такая проблема появилась недавно. Вроде как год назад такого не было, хотя я может тогда не пробовал изменять параметры.